# IOS swift how can I create a custom first cell for a Tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I am using swift 3 and I have a custom `TableView`.

However I am trying to make the first row completely different from all the others . It's like the Facebook app where the first row has a TextBox that states "What's on your mind ? " and the rest of the tableView is the same .

My custom TableView looks like this:

[image]

I now want to put a TextView on the first TableView row, how can I go about doing that?

this is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC


  cell.post.text = Posts[indexPath.row]
  cell.fullname.setTitle(FullName[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
  cell.fullname.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.fullname.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomePageC.Fullname_Click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  cell.comments.setTitle(Comments[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
  cell.comments.tag = indexPath.row

  cell.votes.setTitle(Votes[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)      cell.votes.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.time.text = Times[indexPath.row]
  cell.shares.setTitle(Shares[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
  cell.shares.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.location.text = Locations[indexPath.row]
  cell.vote_status.text = VoteStatus[indexPath.row]

  return cell
}
```

Comment: just a note: you should name your variables lowercased, to distict it from classes

Comment: and you should better have an array with a struct/class which holds all data per cell. thats more easy to hande and put all infos together in one object. ( `User(posts: 2, fullName: "Full Name", comments: 3, votes: 2 ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table view header which will be at the top of the section and can be different from the custom reuseable cells you call in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Check out this example it should get you started. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-section-header-to-a-table-view

Answer (score 1):

create an second cell and give this cell back on first row, use a different identifier for the firstrowcell.

note: also return on other callbacks (like height) depending on indexPath.row == 0

Answer (score 1):

option 1:
use two sections, section 1 return only 1 cell

option 2:
create a custom cell, then in your `tableview` methods, use logic like if `indexPath = 1`, then `cell as custom cell`, otherwise `cell as prototype cell`

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 cells then have the following logic in the cellForRow function:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
    //Do things
} else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC
    //Do other things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it...

You need to use a custom Model, Cell, and XIB.

First set up your variables:

```
var results: [Results] = []
```

Then you set up your custom model:

```
struct Results {

var location: String

init(description: String, company_name: String, places: String){
    self.location = location
}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    print("return")
    return [
        "location": location,
    ]
}
```

Then append to your Model with:

```
resultsReturn = Results(description: description!..... etc)
```

Then you create your ResultsCell.swift file and create a new function:

```
func configureForResults(results: Results) {
print(results)
}
```

When you create the ResultsCell.swift be sure to check the box for "Create XIB" then in the XIB, add your labels, pictures and anything else you want.

Then connect the labels and the outputs in your ResultsCell.swift file and then in the configureForResults:

```
location.text = results.location
```

Then in your cellForRowAt:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! ResultsCell
let result = resultsReturn[indexPath.row];
cell.configureForResults(results: self.result)
return cell
} else {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC
//Do other things
}
```

You will then need to create the AwakeFromNib function and there's one other thing you have to do, I just cannot find it because my laptop just died. I will update this answer once I get it powered up.